# Find 2d point given 2d point and transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a 1x3 matrix representing a point in space:

```
[x]
[y]
[1]
```

And a 3x3 matrix representing an affine 2d transformation matrix

```
[a][b][c]
[d][e][f]
[g][h][i]
```

How to I multiply the matrices so that I am given the matrix?

```
[newX]
[newY]
[w]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I happen to have some experience in computer vision. The vector $u=[x,y,1]^T$ seems homogeneous coordinates of a 2D point. Let $v=Au$ where $A$ is an affine transformation matrix. I think you can get the coordinates of the new point by multiplying a scalar factor such that the third entry of $v$ is $1$. That is $x_{new}=v(1)/v(3), y_{new}=v(2)/v(3)$.

Comment: it is a $3*1$ matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Basic matrix multiplication works here.

$$ \begin{bmatrix} c_x \\ c_y \\ c_w \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ c_x = a\, x + b\, y + c $$
$$ c_y = d\, x + e\, y + f$$
$$ c_w = g\, x + h\, y + i$$

with your new point at $(x,y) = (c_x/c_w, c_y/c_w)$

You will find examples [here](http://www.ia.hiof.no/~borres/cgraph/math/twod/p-twod.html).

Comment: +1 for the image, but the link is broken. Can I get a newer one?

Comment: try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xzu8_Fe3ImI and http://mrl.nyu.edu/~dzorin/igf06/lecture05/lecture05.pdf